# Why does PyWaffle raise a UserWarning and produce an unexpected pictogram with the "icons" argument?

Tags: python, matplotlib, waffle-chart

I have been trying to follow [the steps described in the PyWaffle documentation](https://pywaffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/plot_with_characters_or_icons.html#icons) to use icons instead of the default blocks. Yet even when I run a simple example that I took from [Python-Charts.com](https://python-charts.com/part-whole/waffle-chart-matplotlib/):

```
from pywaffle import Waffle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
value = [12, 22, 16, 38, 12]

# Waffle chart
plt.figure(
    FigureClass = Waffle,
    rows = 10,
    columns = 10,
    values = value,
    icons = 'face-smile')

plt.show()
```

I get the following error and an unexpected figure:

```
C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py:861: UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. The bottom and top margins cannot be made large enough to accommodate all axes decorations.
  func(*args)
```

[Unexpected result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZTpH.png)

Running the code above, I expected the following result to be produced:

[Waffle Chart with icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLmhB.png)

However, the following example, also taken from the Python-Charts website, produces the expected results:

```
from pywaffle import Waffle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
value = [12, 22, 16, 38, 12]

# Waffle chart
plt.figure(
    FigureClass = Waffle,
    rows = 10,
    columns = 10,
    values = value,
    characters = '♥')

plt.show()
```

[Waffle Chart with characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poNbY.png)

The error previously described only seems to occur when introducing the **icons** argument, yet the project that I'm working on needs to have a specific icon of a person in the graph.

Comment: Could it be that no version of `FontAwesome` is installed?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal pip show fontawesomefree reveals that fontawesomefree-6.1.1 is installed.

Comment: pywaffle seems to sometimes have a problem setting the correct fontsize, but it is unclear what the exact circumstances are.  See https://github.com/gyli/PyWaffle/issues/33   PyWaffle's maintainer can't reproduce the issue yet.