# Fontawesome icons displayed incorrectly in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, font-awesome

I've got some pyplot charts with annotations using fontawesome icons.
Everything worked fine in the past until I was required to update my Python Interpreter from 3.10 to 3.11.

Now e.g. a simple left-arrow looks like this:
[left-arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeTk1.png)

This is the code I'm using:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fmgr

path = '...\\fontawesome-free-5.15.4-desktop\\fontawesome-free-5.15.4-desktop\\otfs\\'
prop = fmgr.FontProperties(fname=path + 'Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf', size=2)
plt.text(0.5,0.5,fa.icons['arrow-left'], fontproperties=prop)
```

I also added the font the font manager by using the following code without success:
`fmgr.fontManager.addfont(path + 'Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf')`

Currently I'm using matplotlib==3.8.1, downgrading to a previous version like 3.7.3 didn't help

I searched a lot but couldn't find anything similar to my issue, therefore it would be really nice if somebody could help along.

Thank you,
Kilian

Comment: This seems to be a windows problem. See also https://github.com/gyli/PyWaffle/issues/33  Unfortunately no solution is provided.

Comment: Thank you very much @JohanC.
It seems that the problem is quite similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75592635/why-does-pywaffle-raise-a-userwarning-and-produce-an-unexpected-pictogram-with-t) (where also no solution is provided yet unfortunately).